How to install Sencha Cmd 7.8.0.59 (linux-amd64) on eclipse-temurin:21 docker image
I'm trying to install Sencha Cmd 7.8.0.59 on the eclipse-temurin:21 docker image;
FROM eclipse-temurin:21 as builder

ENV CMD_VERSION="7.8.0.59"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
        unzip \
        libfreetype6 \
        fontconfig \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /work

RUN wget --no-cookies https://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/${CMD_VERSION}/no-jre/SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh.zip \
    && unzip SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh.zip -d . \
    && chmod o+x SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh \
    && ./SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh -Dall=true -q -dir /opt/Sencha/Cmd/${CMD_VERSION}

However, running the installer fails with
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be 1.8.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.

Running java -version from within an eclipse-temurin:21 container yields
openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

And running `echo "$JAVA_HOME" yields
/opt/java/openjdk

Does anybody have any idea how to get this to work? Is it a bug in the Sencha Cmd 7.8.0.59 installer for Linux? (7.8.0.59 works fine with termurin 21 on my M2 Mac using the osx-arm-installer.)

The error message really says it all - you need to install Java 8 (provided on Ubuntu by the openjdk-8-jdk package) and set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to its location:
FROM eclipse-temurin:21 as builder

ENV CMD_VERSION="7.8.0.59"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
        unzip \
        libfreetype6 \
        fontconfig \
        openjdk-8-jdk \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Point the install to OpenJDK 8
ENV INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
WORKDIR /work
RUN wget --no-cookies https://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/${CMD_VERSION}/no-jre/SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh.zip \
    && unzip SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh.zip -d . \
    && chmod o+x SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh \
    && ./SenchaCmd-${CMD_VERSION}-linux-amd64.sh -Dall=true -q -dir /opt/Sencha/Cmd/${CMD_VERSION}


Although that seems to do the trick, the primary reason for me for upgrading to Sencha Cmd 7.8 is to move away from java 8 altogether. I was hoping for a different solution, but will settle for this in lieu of Sencha Cmd working properly with java 21. Leaving this open for a few more days before accepting the answer.

@BentAndréSolheim This seems to be a limitation on Sencha's side, unfortunately.
